# 301 редирект с `?page=1`на первую страницу категории

Tags: php, laravel

В каталоге на сайте (laravel 5.7) много товаров, которые разбиваются по страницам. Как можно настроить 301 редирект с `?page=1`на первую страницу категории?

В контроллере, который отвечает за показ товаров в каталоге на вход поступает `$request` и `$category`.

```
public function index(Request $request, Category $category = null)
{
    //...
}
```

Я так понимаю, именно тут можно как-то перехватить `?page=1` и сделать редирект. Но как? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Предполагаю что-то такое

```
$page = $request->input('page');
if (!is_null($page) and $page == 1) {
     return redirect(???, 301) //куда редирект?
}
```

Думал `return redirect($request->getPathInfo(), 301);`, но тогда исчезают все другие параметры, которые могут быть в строке (фильтры, например).

Comment: Что мешает добавить в роут необязательный параметр?

Comment: @InDevX это как? мой роут сейчас `Route::get('/catalog/{category?}', 'CatalogController@index')->name('catalog.index');`

Comment: Ну и редиректиться значит надо на тот же роут `catalog.index`.